# Error with qt.qpa.xcb and qt.qpa.plugin when trying to install gpt4all (https://gpt4all.io/index.html)

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

I am getting below errors with qt.qpa.xcb and qt.qpa.plugin when trying to install gpt4all (https://gpt4all.io/index.html)

[image]

**System:**
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

**What I have tried:**
I have already tried the below from suggestions I could find on similar questions on stackoverflow and other websites.

```
# Install/Reinstall modules
sudo apt-get install qt5-xcb
sudo apt-get --reinstall install qt5-xcb
sudo apt install --reinstall libxcb-xinerama0

xhost +local:
export DISPLAY=:0.0
export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?